# How to disable asp.net control in client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I want to disable Asp.net textbox on the client side using javascript if it's not empty.

I am using the following function for empty check and to disable the textbox.

```
<script>    
   function check(textBox) {
     if (textBox.innerText = (field.value === "")) { 
         textBox.disabled = true; 
     } 
   }    
</script>
```

and the following code which I used in pageload

```
ASPxTextBox1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "check(this);");
```

and following is my aspx.

```
  <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="44px">
          <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="function check(textBox)" />
  </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

It's not working for me. I don't know what's the problem.
Is there any way to achieve the same.

Note: I am using DevExpress ASPxTextBox controls.

Comment: change TextChanged="function check(textBox)  to  TextChanged="function check(this)".

Comment: @HamedJavaheri still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole function looks like as below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function OnTextChangedHandler(s) {
         alert('TextChanged. Text = ' + s.GetText());

         s.SetEnabled(false);
    }
</script>
```

Your html is as bellow.

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" ClientInstanceName="txtReceiver" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="44px">
    <ClientSideEvents
        TextChanged="function(s, e) {
            OnTextChangedHandler(s);
        }" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Since this is a  `ASPxTextBox` according to their documentation `s.SetEnabled(false);` this code can be used to disable the control.
`s.GetText()` can be used to get the text value from the control.
 For more info check this [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B220598/aspxtextbox-the-client-side-textchanged-and-valuechanged-events-are-not-raised-when).

Comment: Yeah. And you can call this function as `check()` I have edited my answer just check it and try again.

Comment: i did it as u said but still i can edit textbox content even if it has already text :/

Comment: Is the line inside the function is  executed. To check that just write a single line of code as `console.log("test"); `or use alert as `alert('some message');` as the fist line inside the function

Comment: no it isn't .. should i edit anything in pageload page ? i mean c# code ? i put alert in my function and it didn't work

Comment: Try this `<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="44px">
          <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="check()" />
  </dx:ASPxTextBox>`

Comment: still nothing changed and no alert is shown i thing function doesn't executed what i should do ?

Comment: `<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="44px" onchange="check();"> 
         
  </dx:ASPxTextBox> ` try this and let me know is it working if not also try this one `<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="44px"> <ClientSideEvents onchange="check();"/> </dx:ASPxTextBox>`

Comment: code doesn't accept 'onchange' only 'textchanged' and it doesn't work when i add ;

Comment: I think you are using devExpress ASPxTextBox control so I have edited my answer just check it.

Comment: Yeah .. finally i'm sorry.. u deserve more than one accept i didn't know that devexpress has another syntax :)

Comment: In your question also you have to mention that you are using  DevExpress ASPxTextBox control. So that it will be more easy to focus on it's own syntax. Any way thanks.